# Gripper Error When Trying to Lift A Material

Tags: gazebo, ros2, collision, gripper, pick-and-place

I am trying to lift a cylinder with a very simple gripper but when the gripper closes, the cylinder goes through the gripper. The gray cylinder cannot be lifted by the yellow finger. So I cannot lift it. What is wrong? What is my mistake? What should I do? Could you please help me? Below there is URDF File and World File. You can see the problem from the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P20y9gBq1As

URDF FILE FOR THE GRIPPER

```
<link name="right_fingertip">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <box size="${right_fingertip_length} ${right_fingertip_width} ${right_fingertip_height} "/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <material name="yellow"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="${right_fingertip_length} ${right_fingertip_width} ${right_fingertip_height} "/>
        </geometry>
        <contact_coefficients mu="0" kp="1000.0" kd="1.0"/>
    </collision>
    <xacro:box_inertia m="0.5" l="${2*right_fingertip_length}" w="${2*right_fingertip_height}" h="${2*right_fingertip_width}" 
                       xyz="0 0 ${right_fingertip_height / 2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>

<link name="left_finger">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <box size="${left_finger_length - left_finger_height} ${left_finger_width} ${left_finger_height}"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="${left_finger_length /2} 0 0"/>
        <material name="yellow"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="${left_finger_length / 2} 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="${left_finger_length - left_finger_height} ${left_finger_width} ${left_finger_height}"/>
        </geometry>
        <contact_coefficients mu="0" kp="1000.0" kd="1.0"/>
    </collision>
    <xacro:box_inertia m="0.5" l="${2*left_finger_length}" w="${2*left_finger_height}" h="${2*left_finger_width}" 
                       xyz="0 0 ${left_finger_height / 2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>

<link name="left_fingertip">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <box size="${left_fingertip_length} ${left_fingertip_width} ${left_fingertip_height} "/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <material name="yellow"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="${left_fingertip_length} ${left_fingertip_width} ${left_fingertip_height} "/>
        </geometry>
        <contact_coefficients mu="0" kp="1000.0" kd="1.0"/>
    </collision>
    <xacro:box_inertia m="0.5" l="${2*left_fingertip_length}" w="${2*left_fingertip_height}" h="${2*left_fingertip_width}" 
                       xyz="0 0 ${left_fingertip_height / 2.0}" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>




enter code here<model name='Rebar1'>
  <link name='link_0'>
    <inertial>
      <mass>29.66920102</mass>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>356.03115398</ixx>
        <ixy>0.00000001</ixy>
        <ixz>0.00000001</ixz>
        <iyy>356.03115398</iyy>
        <iyz>0.00000001</iyz>
        <izz>0.00148346</izz>
      </inertia>
      <pose>0 0 0 1.57 -0 0</pose>
    </inertial>
    <pose>0 0 -0 0 -0 0</pose>
    <gravity>1</gravity>
    <self_collide>0</self_collide>
    <kinematic>0</kinematic>
    <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
    <visual name='visual'>
      <pose>0 0 0 1.57079 -0 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder>
          <radius>0.01</radius>
          <length>12</length>
        </cylinder>
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <lighting>1</lighting>
        <script>
          <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
          <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
        </script>
        <shader type='pixel'>
          <normal_map>__default__</normal_map>
        </shader>
        <ambient>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</ambient>
        <diffuse>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</diffuse>
        <specular>0.01 0.01 0.01 1</specular>
        <emissive>0 0 0 1</emissive>
      </material>
      <transparency>0</transparency>
      <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
    </visual>
    <collision name='collision'>
      <laser_retro>0</laser_retro>
      <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
      <pose>0 0 0 1.57079 -0 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder>
          <radius>0.01</radius>
          <length>12</length>
        </cylinder>
      </geometry>
      <surface>
        <friction>
          <ode>
            <mu>1</mu>
            <mu2>1</mu2>
            <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
            <slip1>0</slip1>
            <slip2>0</slip2>
          </ode>
          <torsional>
            <coefficient>1</coefficient>
            <patch_radius>0</patch_radius>
            <surface_radius>0</surface_radius>
            <use_patch_radius>1</use_patch_radius>
            <ode>
              <slip>0</slip>
            </ode>
          </torsional>
        </friction>
        <bounce>
          <restitution_coefficient>0</restitution_coefficient>
          <threshold>1e+06</threshold>
        </bounce>
        <contact>
          <collide_without_contact>0</collide_without_contact>
          <collide_without_contact_bitmask>1</collide_without_contact_bitmask>
          <collide_bitmask>1</collide_bitmask>
          <ode>
            <soft_cfm>0.1</soft_cfm>
            <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
            <kp>1e+13</kp>
            <kd>1</kd>
            <max_vel>0.01</max_vel>
            <min_depth>0</min_depth>
          </ode>
          <bullet>
            <split_impulse>1</split_impulse>
            <split_impulse_penetration_threshold>-0.01</split_impulse_penetration_threshold>
            <soft_cfm>0.1</soft_cfm>
            <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
            <kp>1e+13</kp>
            <kd>1</kd>
          </bullet>
        </contact>
      </surface>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <static>0</static>
  <allow_auto_disable>1</allow_auto_disable>
  <pose>5.99887 2.38405 0 0 -0 0</pose>
</model>
```